# Has Sharesight calculated my dividend's foreign source income correctly?

Tags: etf, dividends, australia, foreign-income, online-tools

I recently received my first dividend from the ASX:IVV S&P 500 ETF. In the [Components of Distributions](https://cdn-api.markitdigital.com/apiman-gateway/ASX/asx-research/1.0/file/2924-02326441-2A1272272?access_token=83ff96335c2d45a094df02a206a39ff4) announcement it says that the Foreign Sourced Income is 99.9998% of the cash distribution.

I have a [Sharesight](https://sharesight.com) account for tracking dividends, and am confused by how it broke down this dividend. Rather than putting 100% into Foreign Source Income, it put only 1%.

[image: screenshot from Sharesight]

Who's at fault here: my understanding, or Sharesight? It's definitely possible that Sharesight has imported the wrong data, but that would surprise me as it is, you know, its One Job.

Also, should I be tracking the "Foreign withholding tax gross-up" portion of the dividend? Is that what the bottom option here refers to?

[image: screenshot showing the option to add a "Foreign Tax Withheld/Offset" field]